# Gmail like ajax page refresh in liferay

Tags: javascript, ajax, liferay-6

We are a having search page(jsp) in our Liferay portlet which contains approximately 30 fields. When a person selects some parameter and press submit button then the action method is called and result are shown on the different jsp page. Which is the default behavior.

What we want to implement is that when a person submits the search form then the page must be ajax refreshed on the basis of those parameters.

What our understanding is that we can append the parameters in the URL and make the ajax call.Like in gmail if you do advanced search then the parameters are appended on the URL.

we can appended parameters into url so that when a user pastes url on the browser directly then a action method is called, jsp is loaded and then a java-script will read the parameters from the URL and fetch the proper data.

According to us the problem that we would be facing will be saving of the history in the browser so that whenever the page is changed due to ajax call and user clicks on the browser back button then the previous HTML state should be saved.

Is the above approach correct? 
What could be the further issues that we can face while implementing the same?
How can we save the history so as to preserve the previous state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using the BBQ plugin. The BBQ plugin works on the hash tag change of the URL.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/